# HTML5- using jQuery methods to hide and show html elements isn't working?

Tags: html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var width = $(window).width();
  if (width < 768) {
    $("video").hide();
    $(".hero img").show();
  } else {
    $(".hero img").hide();
    $("video").show();
  }
});
```

```html
<header class="masthead">
  <div id="hero">
    <img src="img/physio.jpg">
    <video playsinline autoplay loop muted>
      <source src="video2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</header>
```

I want when in mobile mode to switch from video to image

why this isn't working?

Comment: hero is an id in your html, but you used it as a class in JQuery

Comment: Also your code only runs when the page loads, it should also run when the viewport width changes.You could also do this with a media query.

Comment: @Tanim yes my bad, but the video element still doesn't hide/show

Comment: Use CSS: `@media (max-width: 767.98px) { video { display: none } #hero img { display: none; } }  video { display: block } #hero img { display: inline-block }`

Comment: @HereticMonkey It works but, does that mean both the image and video will be loaded when visting the website or just one of them depending the screen size?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple hide/show example of JQuery `$(window).width()`, try your snippet on this one, and please lemme know if it works or not. *It's better if you get the code from below and try it on your own computer because it's related to window size.*

```
<header class="masthead">
  <div id="hero">
    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
  </div>
</header>

<style>
 .green, .red {
   padding: 30px;
   width: 100px;
   margin: 30px auto;
 }
 .green {background: green;}
 .red {background: red;}
</style>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
      if ($(window).width() > 767) {
        $(".green").hide();
      }
      if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        $(".red").hide();
      }
  });
</script>
```